# Is there another option besides MythTV for watching video files with remote control access?

Tags: remote

For one computer I have, I'd like to be able to watch videos I have in a local directory on the monitor, but be able to control which files play, and be able to pause, rewind, fast forward, and so on, from my Android tablet.

I have set up a Mythbuntu computer before, with Android remote capability, but that seems overkill with so many features, when all I want to do is to be able to play video files.

I looked into VLC Remote, but after some investigation, I'm unclear if the VLC remote allows me to control what's on the main computer monitor (which is what I want), or plays video on the Android device (which is not what I need).

Is there some set up that will allow me to remotely control videos on my Ubuntu computer monitor from my Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled on using VLC, with VLC remote, to watch videos. It's simple to set up, and some automatic features are quite good.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [XBMC](http://xbmc.org). From what I gather from your post, it has everything you want.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. XBMC does seem to have the features I want, but it also seems to be as feature rich and as large as MythTV, so I'm not sure if I'm benefitting over using MythTV.

Comment: Fair enough; I have XBMC running on a Raspberry Pi taped to the TV, and I use it only to play videos, which works practically out of the box.